# Trigger error at the compilation if bad value for enum

Tags: c

I'd like to know if I can trigger `#error` if value of multiple `enum` are bad. For example I have this enum

```
enum config_choice {
  YES,
  NO
};

enum config_choice PARAM_1 = YES;
enum config_choice PARAM_2 = NO;
enum config_choice PARAM_3 = YES;

....
```

For example I'd like to have something like this

```
if(PARAM_1 == YES && (PARAM_2 == YES || PARAM_3 == YES)   ){
    #error "Bad configuration!!!"
}
```

Enum values will never change during runtime.

Comment: You want to mix compile-time error checking with run-time variables. That's not possible. Use `constexpr` to make the variables compile-time constants. Then use [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert) to do a compile-time check. But remember, then you can't change the values at run-time. You have to pick one or the other, you can't have both.

Comment: Sounds like the actual problem is bad identifier naming.

Comment: Update to my previous comment: I thought this was tagged C++ for some reason, so linked to wrong static assertion. [Here's the C static assert link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Static_assert).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit: Adaption to C11/C23:*

Since C11 this is supported by [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Static_assert) – until upcoming C23 you'll need to 
`#include <assert.h>` for, as it is only a macro mapping it to `_Static_assert` (which you might apply as well, but will get deprecated with C23 which makes the former a keyword as well).

You will need, though, *compile time constants* for (as with the old-school variant below), so you need to:

```
#define PARAM_1 YES
#define PARAM_2 NO
#define PARAM_3 YES
```

(Thanks @[StoryTeller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817643/storyteller-unslander-monica) for the hint.)

---

*Old-school (pre-C11) variant:*

Per se such things are not supported – but you can still achieve compilation breaking by using a little trick for: Creating or defining an array of negative size!

This can look as follows (general case):

```
typedef int StaticCheck[-(theFailureCondition)];
// or:
typedef int StaticCheck[-!(theSuccessCondition)];
```

So for your specific example:

```
enum config_choice
{
  YES,
  NO
};

// though you need compile time constants for (!):
#define PARAM_1 YES
#define PARAM_2 NO
#define PARAM_3 YES
// enum config_choice PARAM_X = ...;
// is not; not even if you apply const to:
// enum config_choice const PARAM_Y = ...;

typedef int ConfigCheck[-(PARAM_1 == YES && (PARAM_2 == YES || PARAM_3 == YES))];
```

This makes the compilation fail (your goal), though resulting error messages are pretty unfortunate, of course.

If you need many such checks you might create a macro for, e.g.

```
#define STATIC_ASSERT(CONDITION) \
    typedef int CONCAT(StaticCheck_, __LINE__)[-!(CONDITION)]
// note the naming: we want to  a s s e r t, thus want to fail on opposite value
#define CONCAT(X, Y) CONCAT_(X, Y) // classic token concatenation...
#define CONCAT_(X, Y) X ## Y
```

Of course you cannot define more than one test on the same line, but that wouldn't be recommended anyway (even less readable error messages).

For your specific case:

```
STATIC_ASSERT(PARAM_1 != YES || (PARAM_2 != YES && PARAM_3 != YES));
// (inverted condition, see above)
```

Demonstration (with macro) on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Kdsnb8he6).

Comment: That's a lot of work to re-implement c11's `_Static_assert`

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Indeed – missed that update in C…